# NSUserDefaults and alertView

Tags: ios, xcode, nsuserdefaults, uialertview

I am creating a Disclaimer that will be shown when the user first launches the app. The disclaimer is an alertView with 2 option. If user agrees then firstViewController will display. If he doesn't he will be redirected to another viewController. But I can't get the disclaimer to disappear if the user agrees the first time. It is shown every time the app launches. Any help would be appreciated. Thank you in advance..

```
NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];

      if (![[defaults valueForKey:@"keyDisclaimer"] isEqualToString:@"accepted"]) {

UIAlertView *disclaimer = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Read Before use" message:@"By using this app you agree to its terms and conditions.\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\ntext heren\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"No!" otherButtonTitles:@"Yes Let me In", nil];

[disclaimer show];

}

// Override point for customization after application launch.
return YES;
}

-(void) alertView:(UIAlertView *) alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex{
NSString *buttonString = {[alertView buttonTitleAtIndex:buttonIndex]};

if ([buttonString isEqualToString:@"Yes Let me In"]) {
    NSMutableDictionary* defaultValues = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];

    [defaultValues setValue:@"accepted"forKey:@"keyDisclaimer"];

    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] registerDefaults:defaultValues];



}
else if ([buttonString isEqualToString:@"No!"]) {
    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Sorry!" message:@"You are not allowed to use this app due to the fact that you did not agree to the terms and Conditions. Please exit this app!" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
    [alert show];

 //  [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setValue:@"notAccepted" forKey:@"keyDisclaimer"];
 }

   if ([buttonString isEqualToString:@"OK"]) {
       introViewController *intro = [[introViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"introViewController" bundle:nil];

      _window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];

       _window.rootViewController = intro;
       [_window makeKeyAndVisible];
   }
 }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
NSMutableDictionary* defaultValues = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary]; 
[defaultValues setValue:...forKey:...]
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] registerDefaults:defaultValues];
```

This will register your defaults if they are not set (for the first time)

Also, seems like you're forgetting `[defaults synchronize]` to commit changes after setting values. If so, you don't need the `registerDefaults` method at all.

Like this:

```
if ([buttonString isEqualToString:@"Yes Let me In"]) {
    NSUserDefaults* defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    [defaults setValue:@"accepted"forKey:@"keyDisclaimer"];
    [defaults synchronize];
}
```

Comment: you have a typo. This is maybe a reason.
`[defaultValues setValue:@"accepted"forKey:@"keyDsclaimer"];`

Comment: ok i updated the post about defaults synchronize, seems it's the prob

Answer (score 0):

You want to use something like stringForKey or objectForKey instead of valueForKey.

```
if([[defaults stringForKey:@"keyDisclaimer"] isEqualToString:@"accepted"]) {
```

I've had bad experiences with valueForKey in the past not always working the way I want. That might be what's causing you some problems.